Finding the valid tetrahedrons with smallest volume for the large input file size
I have two files points_small.txt and points_large.txt which contain the list of points on a 3D plane. Each point is defined by its coordinates and an associated number and is presented in the following format: (x, y, z, n), where x, y, and z are floats, and n is an integer ranging from 0 to 100.
I have to Identify the indices of four points that form a 'valid' tetrahedron with the smallest possible volume.
A valid tetrahedron has to be formed with points such that the sum of their n values is equal to 100
Example:

Suppose these are the following points:

(3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 22)
(2.00, 3.00, 3.00, 3)
(1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 4)
(3.50, 4.50, 5.50, 14)
(2.50, 3.50, 3.50, 24)
(6.70, 32.20, 93.0, 5)
(2.50, 3.00, 7.00, 40)

A tetrahedron formed by the points with indices 0, 3, 4, 6 is the only valid tetrahedron in this example; because 22 + 14 + 24 + 40 = 100

The output should list the zero-based indices of these four points in ascending order.
Hence the output is [0, 3, 4, 6].

I have the following code which is working for smaller data sets here it is :
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

# Function to calculate the volume of a tetrahedron given four points
def tetrahedron_volume(a, b, c, d):
    mat = np.array([
        [a[0] - d[0], a[1] - d[1], a[2] - d[2]],
        [b[0] - d[0], b[1] - d[1], b[2] - d[2]],
        [c[0] - d[0], c[1] - d[1], c[2] - d[2]]
    ])
    volume = np.abs(np.linalg.det(mat)) / 6
    return volume

# Read the points from the file
def read_points(file_path):
    points = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            point = tuple(map(float, line.split(',')))
            points.append(point)
    return points

# Filter points based on weights summing to 100
def filter_points_by_weight(points):
    weight_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, point in enumerate(points):
        weight_groups[int(point[3])].append((idx, point))
    valid_combinations = []
    for comb in combinations(weight_groups.keys(), 4):
        if sum(comb) == 100:
            valid_combinations.extend(combinations(
                [item for sublist in [weight_groups[w] for w in comb] for item in sublist], 4))
    return valid_combinations

# Find the smallest tetrahedron from a subset of points
def find_smallest_tetrahedron_subset(tetrahedron_candidates):
    min_volume = float('inf')
    best_tetrahedron = None
    for tetra in tetrahedron_candidates:
        indices, tetra_points = zip(*tetra)
        volume = tetrahedron_volume(*tetra_points)
        if volume < min_volume:
            min_volume = volume
            best_tetrahedron = indices
    return best_tetrahedron, min_volume

# Parallelized search for the smallest tetrahedron
def find_smallest_tetrahedron(points, num_workers=8):
    tetrahedron_candidates = filter_points_by_weight(points)
    min_volume = float('inf')
    best_tetrahedron = None
    
    num_chunks = min(num_workers, len(tetrahedron_candidates))  # Ensure number of chunks does not exceed candidates
    chunk_size = max(1, len(tetrahedron_candidates) // num_chunks)
    chunks = [tetrahedron_candidates[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(tetrahedron_candidates), chunk_size)]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(find_smallest_tetrahedron_subset, chunk) for chunk in chunks]
        for future in futures:
            result_tetrahedron, result_volume = future.result()
            if result_volume < min_volume:
                min_volume = result_volume
                best_tetrahedron = result_tetrahedron
                
    return best_tetrahedron, min_volume

# Main processing function
def process_file(file_path, num_workers=8):
    points = read_points(file_path)
    best_tetrahedron, min_volume = find_smallest_tetrahedron(points, num_workers)

    if best_tetrahedron:
        indices = sorted(best_tetrahedron)
        print(f"Smallest Tetrahedron Points Indices ({file_path}): {indices}")
        print(f"Volume: {min_volume}")
    else:
        print(f"No tetrahedron found with weight sum 100 in {file_path}")

# Test with provided example
test_points = [
    (3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 22),
    (2.00, 3.00, 3.00, 3),
    (1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 4),
    (3.50, 4.50, 5.50, 14),
    (2.50, 3.50, 3.50, 24),
    (6.70, 32.20, 93.0, 5),
    (2.50, 3.00, 7.00, 40)
]

def process_points(points, num_workers=8):
    best_tetrahedron, min_volume = find_smallest_tetrahedron(points, num_workers)

    if best_tetrahedron:
        indices = sorted(best_tetrahedron)
        print(f"Smallest Tetrahedron Points Indices: {indices}")
        print(f"Volume: {min_volume}")
    else:
        print(f"No tetrahedron found with weight sum 100")

# Test with provided test points
process_points(test_points)

# Process the points_small.txt file
process_file('/work/points_small.txt')

# Process the points_large.txt file
process_file('/work/points_large.txt')

but still it is not efficient for the large input files with over 1500 data points. Please help, how I can make my code more optimised for the large input size.
